# Scraping log files in Kubernetes with promtail

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I have been working with the Kubernetes service discovery configuration (`kubernetes_sd_configs`)
in Promtail very successfully to pull the `stderr` and `stdout` streams into Loki for display on Grafana dashboards.

However it seems that if I want to watch specific log files within the containers (`/var/log/apps/error.log`) I have to use a `static_configs`   and specify the targets explicitly.

I have been able to get around this by running Promtail as a sidecar in each pod, pushing the specified files back to the loki instance.

I also saw a workaround that involved using a pv to write the logs to the node however this is not possible as I am limited to one namespace within a multi tenant cluster.

So my requirement is to combine the service discovery configuration of promtail with the static configs ability to read specific log files within the pod. Has anyone had any success in this area?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kubernetes_sd_config`, it can discover the log files on k8 nodes, but first you need to mount the collecting logs volumes onto the host.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this is a multi-tenant cluster and I do not have access to the underlying node.

Comment: You can try promtail `sidecar`, share specific log volumes between the master container and the promtail container by setting up `volumeMounts`. Then, you need set `static_configs` path as the mounting volume mentioned above.